# D3.js creating nested array from csv

Tags: d3.js

I have a csv file with some latitudes / longitudes coordinates. 
I use the following code to read in the file:

```
d3.csv("static/data/wakool.csv", function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        lineArray1 = [data[i].Lat,data[i].Lng]
        console.log(lineArray1)
    }
});
```

The output I get is a lot of arrays that looks like
[lat1,lng1]
[lat2,lng2] and so on.

What I want is an output that looks like [[lat1, lng1], [lat2, lng2], [lat3, lng3]] and so on that I can use later on in the page. How would I go about getting the csv data into that format?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) : `var latlongs = data.map(function(d) { return [d.Lat,d.Lng]; })`

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I can see from the console that it does generate the output format I wanted but when I try to reference latlongs later on in the code, it says its undefined?

Comment: If you reference it outside of the callback function of d3.csv it will be undefined because d3.csv is asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

One way

```
    d3.csv("static/data/wakool.csv", function(data) {
       //map your data to an array
       const nData = data.map(function(ele) {
          return [data[i].Lat, data[i].Lng];
       })
       //access it using array index
       console.log(nData[0][0]) // Lat of item 0
       console.log(nData[0][1]) // Lng of item 0
   });
```

map it o an array of objects with your desirable keys

```
 d3.csv("static/data/wakool.csv", function(data) {
       //map your data to an array
       const nData = data.map(function(ele) {
          return {
           lat: data[i].Lat,
           lgn: data[i].Lng
          }
       })
       //access it using array index
       console.log(nData[0].lat) // Lat of item 0
       console.log(nData[0].lgn) // Lng of item 0
   });
```